# Cannot implicity convert type

Tags: c#, linq, collections

This is not the first time I have been stuck on collections.  I'm missing something here and feeling not just a little frustrated.  This code snippet is designed return the count of the number of 'restaurant reviews' in the REVIEW db that have a specified 'restaurant id.'  Again I'm getting the a "***cannot implicitly covert type***" error.

Thanks in advance!

```
    public IEnumerable<string> getNumReviews(int RestID)
    {
        var NumReviews = from REVIEW in db.REVIEWs
                         where REVIEW.REST_ID == RestID
                         group REVIEW by REVIEW.REVIEW_ID into t
                         select new { REVIEW_ID = t.Key, TagCount = t.Count() };
        return NumReviews;
    }
```

Comment: Your method has a return type of IEnumerable<string> yet your select statement creates a new anonymous object with 2 properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NumReviews` is an `IEnumerable<anonymous type>`, not an `IEnumerable<string>`. In particular, you're returing an enumeration of objects that include a `REVIEW_ID` *and* a count of the tags for each review.

Your best option is to declare a type to encapsulate that information:

```
public class NumReviewInfo
{
    public int ReviewId { get; set; }
    public int NumTags { get; set; }
}
```

Then, select that object from the method:

```
public IEnumerable<NumReviewsInfo> getNumReviews(int RestID)
{
    var NumReviews = from REVIEW in db.REVIEWs
                     where REVIEW.REST_ID == RestID
                     group REVIEW by REVIEW.REVIEW_ID into t
                     select new NumReviewsInfo { ReviewId = t.Key, NumTags = t.Count() };
    return NumReviews;
}
```

Comment: Can you please help me understand the 'NumTags' integer?  The code appears to work.  Thanks!

Comment: `NumTags` is just a property on the `NumReviewInfo` class. When creating a new class, you're allowed to have an initializer block, where you can set public fields/properties on the new object. In this case, the code sets the `ReviewId` on the new object to `t.Key`, and also sets the `NumReviews` property to `t.Count()`. In the method that calls this code, the `NumReviews` property will contain the count that you want.

Comment: One more question & then I promise to leave you alone.  When I try to call the function in my Bus. Logic layer (public IEnumerable<NumReviewInfo> getNumReviews (RestID) -- INTELLISENSE CAN'T FIND THE NumReviewsInfo & underlines it???

Comment: Most likely it's in a different namespace (or even assembly.) Make sure you have the necessary assembly references and `using` statements so that the class is visible to your logic layer.

Comment: This is what the function is returning:  System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[DL.DLgetDetails+NumReviewInfo]

Comment: Ah, so what's happening is that it's returning the query object. Change the last line of the method to `return NumReviews.ToList()` to return a list of objects.

Answer (score 2):

Your method is supposed to return `IEnumerable<string>` but your code is returning a collection of anonymous objects. Obviously the two aren't the same.

It looks like you need to create a concrete type instead of an anonymous type, and then modify your method to return the appropriate collection:

```
public class ConcreteType
{
    public string ReviewId { get; set; }
    public int TagCount { get; set; }
}
```

And then change the method:

```
public IEnumerable<ConcreteType> GetNumReviews(int restId)
{
    return from REVIEW in db.REVIEWs
           where REVIEW.REST_ID = restId
           group REVIEW by REVIEW.REVIEW_ID into t
           select new ConcreteType 
           { 
               ReviewId = t.Key, 
               TagCount - t.Count()
           };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your `NumReviews` collection is typed to an `IEnumerable<anonymous type>` but it's being used as the return of a function that is typed to `IEnumerable<string>`.  You need to either

- Change the select statement to return a `string`
- Change the return type and select statement to produce a concrete type

For example

```
struct Data { 
  internal int REVIEW_ID;
  internal int TagCount;
}

public IEnumerable<Data> getNumReviews(int RestID) {
    var NumReviews = from REVIEW in db.REVIEWs
                     where REVIEW.REST_ID == RestID
                     group REVIEW by REVIEW.REVIEW_ID into t
                     select new Data { REVIEW_ID = t.Key, TagCount = t.Count() };
    return NumReviews;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't guaranteed to get a collection that is enumerable from a query.  You'll have to call `.ToList()` on it to get a List, which is enumerable.

Answer (score 0):

You're returning an anonymous type by doing:

```
select new { REVIEW_ID = t.Key, TagCount = t.Count() };
```

Which is a complex type. Whereas, your method signature is expecting a collection of strings.

You can either:

```
select REVIEW_ID = t.Key
```

which will match your current method signature, or simply change your method signature to return a complex type (Perhaps a `Tuple<string,int>` ?) and:

```
public IEnumerable<Tuple<string,int>> getNumReviews(int RestID)
{
    return
    (
        from REVIEW in db.REVIEWs
        where REVIEW.REST_ID == RestID
        group REVIEW by REVIEW.REVIEW_ID into t
        select new Tuple<string,int>( t.Key, t.Count() );
    );
}
```